# Proof for sequence

Tags: real-analysis

> Let {$x_{n}$} be a sequence of strictly positive real numbers. Suppose that {$x_{n+1}/x_{n}$} is a convergent sequence with
>
> $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_{n}} <1$$
>
> Show that there exists an $N\in \mathbb{N}$ and constant $C>0$ and $0<r<1$ such that $0<x_{n}<Cr^n$ for an $n\geq N$

I understand that ratio between ${x_{n+1}}$ and $x_{n}$ is less than 1. $x_{n}$ has to be greater than 0 for it to be a denominator.

For any $r$ sufficiently close to $1$, and for every $n$ large enough (depending on $r$), we have $\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_{n}} < r$. I'm stuck here.

Answer (score 1):

Note that because $\{x_{n + 1}/x_n\}$ is a convergent sequence satisfying.

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x_{n + 1}}{x_n} < 1$$

Then we can conclude

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x_{n + 1}}{x_n} = c < 1$$

More importantly, there exists $b$ satisfying $c < b < 1$ such that

$$\exists N \; \text{s.t.} \; \forall n \geq N \qquad \frac{x_{n + 1}}{x_n} < b$$

Thus we have

$$x_{N + 1} < b x_N$$
$$x_{N + 2} < b x_{N + 1} < b^2 x_N$$

And in general

$$x_{N + k} < b^k x_N$$

Let $r = b$ and let $C = x_N b^{-N}$, then we get that

$$x_{N + k} < r^{N + k} C$$

as desired

Answer (score 0):

Let $\rho = \lim_n {x_{n+1} \over x_n} < 1$.

Choose $r \in (\rho,1)$, then there is some $N$
such that for $n \ge N$ you have $ {x_{n+1} \over x_n} \le r $.

Show that $x_n \le r^{n-N} x_N = r^n ( {1 \over r^N} x_N)$ for $n \ge N$.

Now figure out what to do with $x_1,...,x_{N-1}$.

> Let $C = \max ({x_1\over r},...,{x_{N} \over r^{N}})+1$.

Comment: I'm still not sure what to do with $x_{1},\dots , x_{N-1}$ but thank you for your answer!

Comment: Choose $C$ large enough so that $C > {x_k \over r^k}$ for $k=1,...,N$.